# dictionary as a class argument in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am just starting Python for solving one project and I am struggling a lot with the syntax and usage as I have coded in type checking language only (Java, C++).
Here I am defining one class and inside that class, I want to store one dictionary of objects but I am not able to access that dictionary in other function of that class. below example give me the same error:

Code:

```
 class abc:
     def __init__(self):
     a =10

  class test:
    def __init__(self):
      self.ddict['xyz'] = abc()

    def access(self):
      self.ddict['def'] = abc()
```

I am getting the error:
**self.ddict['xyz'] = abc()
AttributeError: test instance has no attribute 'ddict'**

Comment: That's right, it doesn't have that attribute. Add e.g. `self.ddict = {}` to `test.__init__`. It's not clear from that example where you expected it would have come from. Give a [mcve] with *correct indentation*.

Comment: oh I thought that self.ddict['xyz'] = abc(), will intiansite the agrument. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your dict before using it. You code should look like this:

```
class abc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10

class test:
    def __init__(self):
      self.ddict = {'xyz': abc()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @jonrsharpe. It worked!

```
class abc:
     def __init__(self):
     a =10

  class test:
    def __init__(self):
      self.ddict = {}  /* need to init first*/
      self.ddict['xyz'] = abc()

    def access(self):
      self.ddict['def'] = abc()
```